# Jenkins pipeline, @Lazy property on object is NULL on first call

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

@Lazy does not appear to be returning the value on first call within a Jenkins pipeline. Any idea as to why?

Code:

```
class JenkinsStatus implements Serializable {
    def pipeline

    @Lazy String author = {
        this.pipeline.echo "Call to Author"
        def commit = this.pipeline.sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD')
        def a = this.pipeline.sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git --no-pager show -s --format='%an' ${commit}").trim()
        this.pipeline.echo("inside Author is: ${a}")
        a
    }()
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage( "Checkout repo") {
            steps {
                // SCM checkout() here.
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                JenkinsStatus jstatus = [
                    pipeline: this
                ]

                echo "Author1: ${jstatus.author}"
                echo "Author2: ${jstatus.author}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the pipeline, I get the following results:

```
Call to Author
[Pipeline] sh
+ git rev-parse HEAD
[Pipeline] sh
+ git --no-pager show -s --format=%an 9242efd51b83b4202863a04ac0b3c45c256a3948
[Pipeline] echo
inside Author is: <edit out>
[Pipeline] echo
Author1: null
[Pipeline] echo
Author2: <edit out>
```

You can clearly see `a` is defined. It's return. But JenkinsStatus.author doesn't actually get applied until the *second* call.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins CPS transformation does funny things with Groovy annotations. I've never been able to get `@Lazy` to work with fields in shared library classes. `@Singleton` works if you have only one class with it in your entire runtime, but fails whenever you add a second one. `@Delegate` doesn't work at all.

---

FWIW, this is an accepted answer (of mine) to a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54590943/6498020

> It's a known Jenkins issue: [JENKINS-45901](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45901)
>
> This has been open since August 2017. Looks like it isn't going to be fixed anytime soon:
>
> > Not sure if there is any particular place where Groovy language support (or lack thereof) is exhaustively documented, but at any rate I would not expect this issue or anything like it to be addressed. The focus going forward is allowing external process execution, not wasting any more time on the CPS engine except in cases of security vulnerabilities or serious regressions.